# Can't install libpng-dev

Tags: apt, png

I use Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

the console prints

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.51-0ubuntu3) but 1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

At first I tried installing libpng-dev in the Software Center, but it crashed when it tried installing libpng-dev. Then I googled, tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f libpng-dev
```

but this didn't help. Maybe I should just reinstall Ubuntu? I'd have no problem with that, would just take me about an hour.

```
$ apt-cache policy libpng12-dev
```

prints

```
libpng12-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.51-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.2.51-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

```
$ apt-cache policy libpng12-0
```

prints

```
libpng12-0:
  Installed: 1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2
  Candidate: 1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.51-0ubuntu3.15.10.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.51-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Look in /etc/apt/preferences or /etc/apt/preferences.d/ to see if you have any package pinning going on. That's what this looks like. Also, have you turned on backports or added other apt repos?

Comment: Nope, /etc/apt/preferences.d/ is empty. I'll try rebooting. Update: no success with rebooting.

Comment: I didn't turn on backports to my knowledge. But I have once run sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe".

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libpng12-dev` say?

Comment: $ apt-cache policy libpng12-dev
libpng12-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.51-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.2.51-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages ......... I've added this to the question to get lines.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy libpng12-0` say?

Comment: @dobey I've added what this prints to the question text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've manually installed some other build of `libpng12-0` it appears. You need to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng12-0=1.2.51-0ubuntu3` and then you will be able to install `libpng-dev`.