# Failure to install libpng-dev in Ubuntu 18.04 due to version mismatch

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, libpng

I am not able to install libpng-dev in Ubuntu 18.04. I'm getting the following error:

```
libpng-dev : Depends: libpng16-16 (= 1.6.34-1) but 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
             Recommends: libpng-tools
```

I have tried to re-install it as described in [Can't install libpng-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720361/cant-install-libpng-dev)

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng16-16=1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

But I get the following error:

```
Reinstallation of libpng16-16 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

I was not able to troubleshoot this online and I desperately need it for my research project to go on.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: A guess from that answer you included. Does `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng16-16=1.6.34-1` work?

Comment: Yeah! Solved, thanks, it was a problem for me in adapting the answer. If you want, put it as a comment so I can upvote you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer you included in the question, use the following command to reinstall `libpng16-16` to the required version:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng16-16=1.6.34-1
```

You should then be able to install `libpng-dev`.

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me.